# Android error launching project on emulator

Tags: android, genymotion

Im trying to run a my project on the GenyMotion emulator and for some reason i keep getting this error, does anyone know why? It was working fine before.

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'Desktop2'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+.
     Required by:
         :Desktop2:unspecified
      > Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle.
         > Could not list versions using M2 pattern 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]'.
            > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/'.
               > jcenter.bintray.com
```

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle file (the outer one, you should have at least 2) change

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'`
to
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'`

if that doesn't help, try changing the repositories part

This is my whole build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

    allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```